# Jquery- how to sort object array according to html structure order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to sort an object array according to the html order/ index on page. Here is my actual html

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#a">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#e">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

After some dynamic logic i get it as object like -

```
$allLink = 
[0] link 1
[1] link 3
[2] link 5
[3] link 2
[4] link 4
```

I want this as index on html like

```
$allLink = 
[0] link 1
[1] link 2
[2] link 3
[3] link 4
[4] link 5
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to start off by defining how you want to sort. You did say by index, but keep in mind the index has a name. So are you wanting to sort the array of index names by alphabetical order? Or do you have another arbitrary sorting idea?

Comment: Thanks Ramirez. Not sure its say index or so. I just need this object as on html order.

Comment: What is the data type of the elements in $allLink? I am assuming they are strings of filenames. In that case simply calling $allLInk.sort() should work if $allLink is an array of strings.

Comment: Well the first thing: Objects do not have indexes. Maybe you mean an array? Second: If you're using jQuery (as you've tagged), then a selector like `var $allLink = $("#navbar").find("a");`, would return a collection of all of the links in the order they appear in the HTML.

Comment: "After some dynamic logic"  What "dynamic logic" are you using?  `$('li a')` returns the links in document order.  If you're trying to capture them as object keys, remember that object keys do not have a defined order. If you want a specific order, you want an array.

Comment: @DanielBeck I've since deleted my comment as I felt it was just a bit unnecessary, it's just helpful to remember in some cases, as many standard array methods wouldn't be available on a jQuery obejct. :)

Comment: @TylerRoper true, you're absolutely right, I was oversimplifying.

Comment: That all in mind, @Jargo, if you could edit your question to add some more detail of what you've attempted (as Daniel Beck requested earlier), it would likely lead us to the solution to your issue. It seems like you don't need any sort of dynamic logic as opposed to some simple jQuery and a bit of structure-massaging.

Comment: add in jsfiddle for sample

Comment: Please post your dynamic logic